# How to save a file to my computer using PHP

Tags: php

I'm using PHP and have a file upload page as well as another page to view the uploaded files.  The problem is that my web server's ftp only allows a maximum upload size of 5MB but I want to be able to upload larger files.

How can I save these files to my laptop instead of to my web server?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You would have to host the PHP page that receives the upload from your laptop.

Comment: So, you want *your website* to upload the files that *users* upload to *your laptop*?  Is that what you are asking?  Aren't you uploading *from* your laptop?  Don't you already have the files?  This question is confusing me.

Comment: By hosting the PHP page that recieves the uploads, can I then still put this live on the web?  If so.. How?

Comment: I'm wondering if the limitation is per-file, as if it were so, you could upload it with a multi-part uploader as http://plupload.com/
Give it a try to see if it solves your issues.

Comment: I just want me and a few people at the moment to be able to upload files to this page, but whatever size they like.  My web server only allows uploads of 5mb, so how do I get around this?
I was thinking do I store them on my laptop instead, and was wondering how to do this.

Comment: @Jack: The files need to be uploaded to the server hosting your PHP page.  I'm assuming your laptop isn't a (permanent) web host.  You can try an uploader that can upload a large file in multiple smaller chunks, like http://fineuploader.com/

Comment: "By hosting the PHP page that recieves the uploads, can I then still put this live on the web?" Don't even THINK about doing that. Unless you really really know what you're doing, your PC-based *AMPP stack will be hacked so fast you won't know what hit you. Besides, you're still faced with the task of getting the file back to the original server after it's been uploaded to your PC.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your possible solution is that, unless you are hosting everything on your laptop, anything that you **upload through your website**, even if it ends up on your laptop in the end, will still have to **pass through your website**.

Since your website has php upload limits, these limits will be applied to anything that is transferred through your website through php.

There are several ways to get around this:

1. Upload everything through FTP (no php).

   Your hosting service has unlimited FTP uploads ("where no file size limits are applied (except for the account size limit)" [source](http://www.000webhost.com/forum/web-programming/23596-change-upload-limit.html#post125872)).  Since it sounds like you only want a small group of people to be able to upload files, give each of them access to your FTP account. Only one FTP account is allowed for free users. If you aren't a free user give them each an individual FTP account in order to monitor individual usage.

   Check out [File Upload Questions](http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php) for some help with FTP.
2. Use a php file splitter.

   Since you are limited to a certain size of file per call, use a ready-built php program such as [Plupload](http://plupload.com) to manage uploading larger files by splitting them into chunks that are small enough to fit through your php limit.  If you are trying to upload a 50MB file with a php limit of 5MB, Plupload will make 10 requests (*10*5MB=50MB*) splitting your file into 10 pieces so that it will pass through the php limit.
3. Use online file transferring software.

   Online programs such as [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [WeTransfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/) allow you to upload and share large files (2GB for WeTransfer and [virtually limitless](https://www.dropbox.com/help/5/en) for DropBox). Any files uploaded and downloaded through this method would go through another company's server (not your own) which means that the 5MB limit would definitely not apply.  Users can create an account with DropBox and upload to a "[shared](https://www.dropbox.com/help/19/en)" folder, or simply upload their files to WeTransfer and you will receive an e-mail that you have a file waiting to be downloaded.

   This method completely skips your server, meaning no 5MB limit, but also meaning that the files won't be stored/accessible on your website.

I hope these suggestions are useful or at least give you something to think about.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

If you can change your php.ini file you could adjust the max upload size

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = “20M”
```

Alternatively you can also do this in your .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

Comment: I don't think, it will be helpful, as OP mentioned that, he/she can't upload bigger file, because his/her ftp server doesn't allowed to upload. So above code won't be helpful in any scenario.

Comment: @jWeavers The above code will override the default setting of 5MB if the hosting provider allows it. How is this not helpful?

Comment: http://www.000webhost.com/forum/web-programming/23596-change-upload-limit.html

It says the limit will be 128MB even if I upgrade to premium.  I'm only messing around at the moment, but I'm looking for a way that any size can be uploaded eventually, that's why I thought saving it to my laptop would work.

Comment: If you want to save it to your laptop then you would need to be running a web server on your laptop with LAMP or WAMP for example and a fixed IP Address and serve the files from there.

Comment: I'm currently using XAMPP, is that okay?
I could get that to work with whatever files I liked, however it wasn't online.  To get it online I had to upload it to my web server.  Apologies for not knowing much, but how do I serve my files from my laptop, but it go online to my website?

Comment: Yeah XAMPP is fine. Within your Apache Folder you will have an htdocs folder. Any file saved in here will be available on your web server. At the minute I assume that your web server is running locally and you are accessing it through localhost or 127.0.0.1 In order to view it online you would need a static ip address for your laptop. This costs money. Would an alternative not be to upload to amazon http://aws.amazon.com/s3/ and serve it from there. You would just link to the file. A quick way to test this is if you have Dropbox place the file in the public folder and copy the public link.

Comment: Okay, I'll try doing it using those two methods.
Just out of interest though, once you have a static IP address, how do you then link files from ht docs to my web server?  Or do they just appear in my web servers ftp and then any file size can be uploaded?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend hosting this yourself as you really need to know what you are doing to run your own web server. From reading the additional information you posted you want multiple people to upload these files. I would suggest you look at the options @Enigmadan has highlighted. If you went for option 3 the form on your site could then be used to post a friendly name and the actual url for the file to a database. This however is two processes for the uploader.